# MariaDB 10.3 тип данных Polygon

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Нужно перенести одну табличку с mysql 5.5 на mariadb 10.3. Таблица содержит в себе данные геозон. Дамп делается успешно, но при вставке в mariadb заканчивается неудачей.

Создание таблицы из дампа:

```
CREATE TABLE `geozone_zones` (
  `gzz_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gzz_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gzz_radius` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `gzz_coordinates` polygon NOT NULL,
  `gzz_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gzz_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=104 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

При вставке строки в таблицу:

> MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO `geozone_zones` VALUES (26, 'UZ', 11071,
>   GeomFromText('POINT(59.8531 30.1712)'), 8889);
>
> ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect POLYGON value: 'POINT' for column
>   'gzz_coordinates' at row 1

Что идет не так?

Comment: Посмотрите документацию на тип данных [polygon](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/polygon/). Как минимум, вы пытаетесь вставить тип `point` в тип `polygon`.

Comment: Это понятно. Но на исходном сервере в этой таблице лежат и point и polygon. В этом то и проблема. Как они смогли там оказаться?

Comment: И дамп в mysql говорит, что так была создана эта таблица, как написано выше.

Comment: Если в старой БД в столбце `gzz_coordinates` хранились `point` и `polygon` одновременно, то вероятно в таблице источнике использовался тип `geometry` для этого столбца.

Comment: все так, как Вы говорите! Спасибо!!!!